# X-Original-For header: what's its purpose?

Tags: http, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

While logging the HTTP headers that are received by my web app (which is behind a load balancer + firewall), I've noticed that I'm receiving the X-Original-For and X-Original-Proto headers (besides the traditional X-Forwared-XXX headers).

What's their purpose?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short Answer: The `X-Original-*` represents the **original header value** received **in `HttpContext.Connection` and `HttpContext.Request`**.

Long Version: When using `Nginx`/`IIS`/`Apache` to setup a reverse proxy, the `HttpContext.Connnection` and `HttpContext.Request` will be changed to the left-most value in `X-Forwarded-*` header, `X-Original-*` headers are used to save the original `HttpContext.Connection` and `HttpContext.Request` values:

1. the original `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` will be saved as header `X-Original-Proto: ...`, and then the `HttpContext.Request.Scheme` will be changed to the left-most scheme in the header of `X-Forwarded-Proto: o1, o2, ...`
2. the original `HttpContext.Request.Host` will be saved as header `X-Original-Host: <original-host>`, and the then `HttpContext.Request.Host` will be changed to the left-most host in the header of `X-Forwarded-Host: o1, o2, ...`
3. the original `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` and `HttpContext.Connection.RemotePort` will be saved as header `OriginalForHeaderName: <original-endpoint>`, and then this value will be changed to left-most IP and port in header of `X-Forwarded-For: o1, o2, ...`

See [source code of saving `X-Original-For`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/026b9df3e0526bae37fb85b18ccb69ec8d71bf30/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs#L297):

```
requestHeaders[_options.OriginalForHeaderName] = new IPEndPoint(connection.RemoteIpAddress, connection.RemotePort).ToString();
```

See [source code of saving `X-Original-Proto`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/026b9df3e0526bae37fb85b18ccb69ec8d71bf30/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs#L316) :

```
requestHeaders[_options.OriginalProtoHeaderName] = request.Scheme;
```

See [source code of saving `X-Original-Host`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/026b9df3e0526bae37fb85b18ccb69ec8d71bf30/src/Middleware/HttpOverrides/src/ForwardedHeadersMiddleware.cs#L333)  :

```
requestHeaders[_options.OriginalHostHeaderName] = request.Host.ToString();
```